# How to check SOAP fault in python when using suds?

Tags: python, soap, suds, bing-ads-api

Trying to use Bing Ads Python API, which uses `suds`, and I am very green about this concept. I frequently encounter an error message as:

> Invalid client data. Check the SOAP fault details for more information

I know this probably means my request has some data format issue. My question is how can I ***Check the SOAP fault details*** as suggested in the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bing Ads API troubleshooting [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingads/guides/handle-service-errors-exceptions?view=bingads-12#python-troubleshooting) has some suggestions e.g.,

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Here are more details about [Using SUDS with Bing Ads API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingads/guides/get-started-python?view=bingads-12#suds).

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you also might need StreamHandler to see the logs in console

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('suds.client').addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```